# ILoggerFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger fails with InvalidOperationException in Release build only

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.5, ninject-logging

Last week the deployment of my Windows Service application to production failed so I tried running the project locally in Release mode and got `InvalidOperationException: Can not determine current class.` that was traced back to a call to `GetCurrentClassLogger`.

My project uses **Ninject** to resolve `ILoggerFactory` into every service in the middle tier. Then the service uses `GetCurrentClassLogger()` to get the proper `ILogger` in the constructor.
For example:

```
public class FooService : IFooService
{
     private readonly ILogger logger;

     public FooService(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
     {
          this.logger = loggerFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger();
     }

     // ... 
}
```

If I dig into the implementation of `GetCurrentClassLogger` at `LoggerFactoryBase` of **Ninject.Extensions.Logging**:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public ILogger GetCurrentClassLogger()
{
  StackFrame stackFrame = new StackFrame(0, false);
  if (stackFrame.GetMethod() == (MethodBase) LoggerFactoryBase.getCurrentClassLoggerMethodInfo)
    stackFrame = new StackFrame(1, false);
  Type declaringType = stackFrame.GetMethod().DeclaringType;
  if (declaringType == (Type) null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Can not determine current class. Method: {0}", (object) stackFrame.GetMethod()));
  return this.GetLogger(declaringType);
}
```

I can see where the exception is being thrown.

My first instinct was to check if any system, framework, or project updates caused it, but nothing meaningful was done since last successful deployment.

Now... the "funny" thing about this issue is that when I added a line with `Trace.WriteLine("Test");` in the constructor, the `GetCurrentClassLogger` executes just fine.

I was able to relate this issue with the compiler's code optimization. If I disable it in the *Build* tab of the project properties, it executes fine too.

**QUESTION**: What could cause `StackFrame` to stop providing the `DeclaringType`?

In the meanwhile I am using this as a workaround, but I would prefer using the original method:

```
this.logger = loggerFactory.GetLogger(this.GetType());
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without looking at the CIL being emitted, it's hard to say **exactly** why the behavior is different, but my guess it's getting inlined. 
You may get the desired results if you attribute your constructor with:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
```

just as the NInject code is doing. It's possible that the method is getting inlined because it's just a single line that assigned a readonly field. You can read a bit about how inlining can affect StackFrames here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReleaseISNOTDebug64bitOptimizationsAndCMethodInliningInReleaseBuildCallStacks.aspx

That said, this kind of unpredictability is why using stack frames are a bad idea. If you want the syntax of not having to specify the class name, are using VS 2012, and your file names match your class names, you can used the CallerFilePath attribute on an extension method and preserve the same behavior as you have now, without using stack frames. See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx

UPDATE:

An alternative approach might be to inject an ILogger directly and have your container be responsible for determining the Type of the component being injected into (since it definitely knows). This seems cleaner too. See example from here: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.logging/issues/19

```
    this.Bind<ILogger>().ToMethod(context =>
    {
        var typeForLogger = context.Request.Target != null
                                ? context.Request.Target.Member.DeclaringType
                                : context.Request.Service;
        return context.Kernel.Get<ILoggerFactory>().GetLogger(typeForLogger);
    });
```

Comment: I'm giving you the bounty even tho I can't accept the answer as solved yet. We are looking into workarounds to avoid the constraints to `MethodImpl` attribute or `StackFrame` in general.

Comment: Why not inject ILogger directly instead of ILoggerFactory and use your container to determine the type of ILogger to create? See updated answer

Comment: I had that binding in the `LoggerModule` but I ran into issues with the injection of `ILogger` that way since all records will show as if they came from `ILogger` (as the current class). It seems to work now so I am guessing there was another issue causing it that got resolved by itself (maybe by Ninject).

Comment: They should not show as if they come from ILogger (because it's not calling GetCurrentClassLogger). typeForLogger in the above example should be the service being injected into.